# Updating Column having index causing deadlock

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb, deadlock, database-administration

```
Update XyzTable set state ='second' where pgmNumber = 'prog123' and state = 'first'
```

State column is low cardinality column having 4 values only. 
Both state & pgmNumber columns has individual index.

There is single row for each pgmNumber.

Deadlock is happening even if above query running concurrently  with different pgmNumber.

What would be the best way to resolve the issue

Comment: the column you are updating is not in where clause ..  so  .. the  related  indexes  are not involved  in the update operatio (but just iìduring the fecth for the rows) ..  could be you have some others user that are inserting or updating the table  while you try to update ..  .. anyway be sure you have autocommit ON or commit fastly after each update so the queue update is not blocked  by not commited  queries

Comment: No it's there in where part

Comment: Dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/266754/updating-column-having-index-causing-deadlock

Answer (score 1):

The deadlock happens because the index page for column "state" is locked by the query.

If the "state" column has only 4 different values, it is likely that the index is not very useful, i.e. it is not speeding up your queries. Please considered removing index for the "state" column.

Also, when reporting InnoDB deadlocks, please post the output of "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS".

Comment: For non-unique indexes, the index is not touched during the query.  Instead the index update is buffered in the "change buffer" for handling later.

Comment: Deadlock happening because of index on 'state' which is getting updated,           
Same query when running concurrently creating deadlock. Is there any option other than removing index. Like putting index hint in query like force or use index(pgmNumber)  ? Will that work?

Answer (score 0):

That `UPDATE` would benefit from a composite index:

```
INDEX(pgmNumber, state)
```

The deadlock probably should not occur.  So, please answer some questions:

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

What query is it deadlocking with?

Is the `UPDATE` part of a multi-statement transaction (`BEGIN...COMMIT`)?  If so, let's see the other queries.

Do you have a `SELECT` on that same row?  If so, does it have `FOR UPDATE` on the end?

It is rarely useful to have an index on a low-cardinality column.  Drop your `INDEX(state)`.

Comment: Same query when running concurrently creating deadlock. Is there any option other than removing index. Like putting index hint in query like force or use index(pgmNumber)  ? Will that work?

Comment: @user2862544 - Removing `INDEX(state)` was cleanup, not a fix for the deadlock.  Adding the composite index is likely to be a fix.

Comment: Thanks Rick, let's suppose that we can not do any ddl change then can we put index hint like force index(pgmNumber) , will that work

Comment: @user2862544 - I don't know for sure.  I would expect the 'hint' to be less good.  What is blocking the DDL change?